# Why is SwifyJSON dictionaryValue empty?

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I'm using SwifyJSON to parse some JSON sent to my iOS app through socket.io and the `.dictionaryValue` of the response is `nil`. Here's how the data is sent from the server:

```
socket.emit('hasBeenMatched', {user: JSON.stringify(currentUser)});
```

Here's what I've got in my iOS app:

```
    socket.on("hasBeenMatched", callback: {data, ack in
        println("got response after requesting match");

        let user = JSON(data!)
        println(user)
        println(user[0])
        println(user[0]["user"])
        println(user[0]["user"].dictionaryValue)

    })
```

And here's the output of that code:

```
got response after requesting match
[
  {
    "user" : "{\"_id\":\"5511c3d8abcdc2fcf7b8fe4b\",\"email\":\"j\",\"password\":null,\"firstname\":\"j\",\"lastname\":\"j\",\"age\":9,\"radius\":\"9\",\"__v\":0,\"wantsToBeMatched\":true,\"matchedWith\":\"k k\"}"
  }
]
{
  "user" : "{\"_id\":\"5511c3d8abcdc2fcf7b8fe4b\",\"email\":\"j\",\"password\":null,\"firstname\":\"j\",\"lastname\":\"j\",\"age\":9,\"radius\":\"9\",\"__v\":0,\"wantsToBeMatched\":true,\"matchedWith\":\"k k\"}"
}
{"_id":"5511c3d8abcdc2fcf7b8fe4b","email":"j","password":null,"firstname":"j","lastname":"j","age":9,"radius":"9","__v":0,"wantsToBeMatched":true,"matchedWith":"k k"}
[:]
```

In an alternate part of my code I have the following code:

```
let request = Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://localhost:3000/api/users/authenticate", parameters: params)
request.validate()
request.response { [weak self] request, response, data, error in
    if let strongSelf = self {
        // Handle various error cases here....

        var serializationError: NSError?

        if let json: AnyObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments, error: &serializationError) {
            println(JSON(json).dictionaryValue)

            // Story board navigation
        } else {
            //Handle error case
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: the output of the `println` in the Alamofire response handling looks like:

```
[_id: 5511c3d8abcdc2fcf7b8fe4b, password: null, __v: 0, lastname: j, age: 9, wantsToBeMatched: true, firstname: j, radius: 9, email: j, matchedWith: k k]
```

What I'm wondering is: why does `println(user[0]["user"].dictionaryValue)` result in `[:]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, but my solution isn't related to SwiftyJSON (which I'm still curious about). I changed how my server sends data over socket. I changed `socket.emit('hasBeenMatched', {user: JSON.stringify(currentUser)});` to `socket.emit('hasBeenMatched', {user: currentUser});`. Essentially, I removed the manual JSON-ification.